# jquery callback function not accessing global function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have 2 functions declared makeAjaxCall and editOrderDetails

editOrderDetails executes makeAjaxCall to go and get a json object with the results of the call.

```
    function editOrderDetails()
{
    makeAjaxCall(
        baseurl+'/orderoutbound/editorderdetails',
        'orderID='+orderID+'&customerReference='+("#orderReference").val()+'&email='+$("#emailAddress").val(),
        function(data){
            if(data.success)
            {
                $("#editOrderDetailsErrorDiv").html(successDiv(data.generalMessage));
                $(".customerReferenceSpan").html(data.order.customerReference);
                $(".emailSpan").html(data.order.emailAddress);

            }else{
                $("#editOrderDetailsErrorDiv").html(errorDiv(data.generalMessage));
                $("#emailAddressErrorDiv").html(data.errors.emailAddress);                  
            }
        }, 
        function(data) {
            $("#editOrderDetailsErrorDiv").html(errorDiv("There was an error.."));
        }
    );
}
```

now i'm using a jquery dialog to work with

```
$("#editOrderDetailsDialog").dialog('destroy').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Edit Order Details',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            buttons:{ 
                "Save": function() { editOrderDetails(); },
                "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            }
        });
```

as my save call back function i'm trying to set my editOrderDetails function.

This however doesnt work and i'm guessing it has something to do with the scopeing.

i have tried declaring var editOrderDetails = function(){}; outside of any and all jquery doc ready functions

i have also tried window.editOrderDetails()
also instead of making a function wrapping the function call

i have tried putting the function into a variable var editOrderDetails = function(){};
then "save" : editOrderDetails

i'm at a loss. any ideas would be appreciated ?

**PS** yes the dialog works correctly. if i place an alert in the callback function it executes when i click save.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var orderID = '<?= $this->orderID; ?>';
var customerID = '<?= $this->customerID; ?>';

//################  PAGE FUNCTIONS ################

//MAKE AN AJAX CALL
    function makeAjaxCall(ajaxUrl, data, functionSuccess, functionFailure){
   $.ajax(
   {
       type: "GET",
       url: ajaxUrl,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: data,
       dataType: "json",
       success: functionSuccess,
       error: functionFailure
   });
}
//END MAKE AN AJAX CALL

//EDIT ORDER DETAILS
function editOrderDetails()
{
    makeAjaxCall(
        baseurl+'/orderoutbound/editorderdetails',
        'orderID='+orderID+'&customerReference='+("#orderReference").val()+'&email='+$("#emailAddress").val(),
        function(data){
            if(data.success)
            {
                $("#editOrderDetailsErrorDiv").html(successDiv(data.generalMessage));
                $(".customerReferenceSpan").html(data.order.customerReference);
                $(".emailSpan").html(data.order.emailAddress);

            }else{
                $("#editOrderDetailsErrorDiv").html(errorDiv(data.generalMessage));
                $("#emailAddressErrorDiv").html(data.errors.emailAddress);                  
            }
        }, 
        function(data) {
            $("#editOrderDetailsErrorDiv").html(errorDiv("There was an error.."));
        }
    );
}
//END EDIT ORDER DETAILS

//################ END PAGE FUNCTIONS ################

$(function() {

// EDIT ORDER DETAILS DIALOG
        $("#editOrderDetailsDialog").dialog('destroy').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Edit Order Details',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            buttons:{ 
                "Save": function() { editOrderDetails(); },
                "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            }
        });
// END EDIT ORDER DETAILS DIALOG
});



//-->

</script>
```

Comment: If you alert in the "editOrderDetails()" function, does it work? Maybe you declared the function at the wrong place.  Would be a problem in "document.ready" function and would be a problem if in another file (.js) called after the one with the dialog details.

Comment: Like Bene said, this probably has to do with where the function is being called. My guess is that "editOrderDetails()" is defined outside of $(document).ready(); this would be an issue becuase you are relying on jQuery dom access before the dom is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a **$** in the call to makeAjaxCall.

```
'orderID='+orderID+'&customerReference='+("#orderReference").val()+'&email='+$("#emailAddress").val(),
```

Becomes:

```
'orderID='+orderID+'&customerReference='+$("#orderReference").val()+'&email='+$("#emailAddress").val(),
```

Comment: thanks for the help. that was the problem. you can look at something for hours on end and missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This http://jsfiddle.net/jQRyq/8/ works fine for me, could you post a bit more of your code for context? Specifically where the `editOrderDetails` functions is defined.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include a cut down version of the script. the script is actually 1000 lines long at this point so i didnt want to overwhelm everyone with code. kept it to the import parts.

Comment: ok your right it is infact a problem with my makeajaxcall function :S

Comment: I think you should remove this question and if you have another one for the call to `$.ajax` then create a new question.

Comment: ok your right it is infact a problem with my makeajaxcall function :S   placing an alert inside the editOrderDetails function gets called. but the makeAjaxCall() doesnt get called...

Comment: i have no issue with $.ajax or really the makeAjaxCall() function. becase both work fine when being called in other parts of the script. its run 3 times to connect and get information when the page first loads